# How can pass current array data to other intent or activity when button is clicked?

Tags: android, arrays, onclicklistener

In given code, what is the simple way of passing current array data to another activity ? I want to pass jsonData.getString("date") and jsonData.getString("start_time") to another activity.

```
    JSONObject jsonData;
    TableRow row1 = new TableRow(this);

    for (int i = 0; i < beaconsArray.length(); i++) 
     {
           jsonData =   beaconsArray.getJSONObject(i);
           row1     =   new TableRow(this);

           TextView textview    =   new TextView(this);
           textview.setText(jsonData.getString("date"));
           textview.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
           textview.setWidth(165);
           row1.addView(textview);

           textview=    new TextView(this);
           textview.setText(jsonData.getString("start_time"));
           textview.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
           textview.setWidth(90);
           row1.addView(textview); 


           ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
           iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.view_btn);
           iv.setOnClickListener(ViewDetail_of_Beacon);
           row1.addView(iv);
     }



     public OnClickListener ViewDetail_of_Beacon = new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

                // Here i need current array data ??


            }
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you not using a listview? instead of a table

Within the listview you can easily set your custom onclicklistner which gives you acces to your row data

example of a onclicklistner:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2,long itemID) {
        String fromDate = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.fromDate)).getText().toString();
    }
});
```

Comment: i will check that. i use table as i thought i can set different field width in it easily

Comment: read this link how to customize your listview with a custom xml file:

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Comment: but am i able to show this output http://cubixshade.com/images/align_row.jpg  using listView ?

Comment: yes, that will be possible, you can insert a table in each row as you like

Comment: well listView is little complex. but I am setting each button id i.e  iv.setId(num) where num helps me figure out which record to send as I have this array beaconsArray.getJSONObject(num) so setting array index as image button id, I am able to pass the current jsonData.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass 2 Strings to another activity.

```
use intent.putExtra(tag,data);
```

If you want to pass an array of objects, set a static variable in another class that you use singleton pattern and get variable by a getter  method.

Comment: i want to pass an array of data when button is clicked, the relevant row data i.e array of data should be passed to another page or activity ?